# Electronic configuration and symmetry labels of 3d$^7$ ions

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, crystals

In 3d$^7$ ions, e.g. Co$^{2+}$, the ground state is $^4$F, and it contains different levels due to the crystal field, such as $^4T_{1g}$, $^4T_{2g}$ and $^4A_{2g}$. Can anyone tell me what exactly these symbols mean? I need to know the exact configuration, not just "the even/odd symmetry of wavefunction". Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Transition-metal-Ions-Stanley-Griffith/dp/101434252X/

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Atomic-Spectra-U-Condon/dp/0521092094/

Comment: You don't have to buy these books, they are in the public domain, so feel free to "steal" the PDF via the internet...